# Would socket.io be too much for a simple service monitor?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, ejs, microservices

I am making a small service that will ping all the other services hosted on my server, this service will ping every other deployed service ever few seconds thus bringing data continuously.

I would be using EJS to render this data in a simple tabular format the data would be URL to the service, response time, status of the service.

So as the data may or may not change after every ping would it be too much to use socket.io and are there any other options available for such scenario which are much more feasible and simpler?

Comment: I am not aware about this concept, could you provide some reference?

Answer (score 0):

Your're not the first developer with a monitoring problem! Use something already in existence like:

- Implement a health/ready enpoint in your service
- use [Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) to ping that service and pump the results to a metrics storage (for example InfluxDB, or [anything else that is supported](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf#output-plugins))
- then deploy a frontend like [grafana](https://grafana.com/) to display the aggregated data...

Bottom line - do yourself a favour and stick with something established and do not write something yourself that others have already solved for you! I've used all of these components and they saved me tonns of time and are thousands of times more powerfull that anything I could have produced myself!

Comment: I know reinventing the wheel would be a waste of time and efforts, but I am writing these services for practice and fun, also at the same time I am also interested in other options such as someone mentioned polling in comments section(which seems to be deleted now). But the options you provided are definitely something I'll implement when going for production monitoring. Sorry I didn't mention that in my question. Thanks for taking time to provide these refernces.